# How to correctly set socket.io ports? Getting socket.io.js 404

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following setup, according to the documentation:

Client-side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect(); // TIP: .connect with no args does auto-discovery
```

Server-side:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    user = require('./routes/user'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app).listen(80),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Why am I getting

```
GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried switching to `server = http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000),` bu then I got `warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES` and same 404. What am I missing here about the port usage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't create a server on port 80 without special permissions. And on another sidenote, you are trying to create 2 servers (one on port 80 and another one on port 3000).

Here's (a part of) what i'm using for my projects:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , sio = require('socket.io').listen(server)

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

// configure your socket.io instance here

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  // server started
});
```

Comment: there are not enough up-votes in the world to express my gratitude! I'v been struggling with it days now... Just one question, I thought socket required a port of it's own, it's not true? it has to run same as the app?

Comment: I used `sudo` to run it on port 80

Comment: I don't recommend sudo'ing nodejs processes. Instead of that, use a frontend-proxy server like nginx or haproxy (there are alot of tutorials around on that topic).