# 404 GET in socket.io server in a Django template

Tags: javascript, django, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to work with Socket.io and Django in a project and when I load the socket.io script from the server

```
<script src="localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

I get an error because my Django project is in localhost:8000 so I dont know why the socket.io script is trying to do requests from Django when I said that the socket.io server is in port 3000.

In js console in my browser says

> > GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=polling&t=142197415699051
> >     404 (NOT FOUND)

and that should be looking to loacalhost:3000 and not to localhost:8000

My Django log console says:

> [22/Jan/2015 18:50:23] "GET
>   /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421974222989-62 HTTP/1.1" 404
>   7506

Obvously because theres not a Django url to answer that request.

How can I load a socket.io server in a Django template???

Comment: is `loacalhost` a typo?

Comment: Yes that was a typo. Sorry but thats not the problem

Comment: Try `localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` in your browser's url bar to verify that you get the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify what port a server-side application listens to from a client-side script src attribute.

You have to configure what port socket.io uses on the server-side.
See [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353638/how-to-correctly-set-socket-io-ports-getting-socket-io-js-404) for an answer on how to do that.